# How can I highlight a listviewitem in listview by programming in Winform?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Just like clicking on the listviewitem by hand, and it turns blue.

Comment: Show what you have tried. show what your code looks like - that way we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Go this way:

```
Listview lv = new ListView();   // Maybe lv.MultiSelect = false  

// Add your items

lv.Items[<index>].Focused = true;
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this, the Item is selected but not highlighted, still white.

Answer (score 1):

Set selected property of the listview item to true.

```
myListView.Items[indexNumber].Selected = true;
myListView.Items[indexNumber].Focused = true;
```